# Como verificar valores do formulário antes de envia-lo JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Preciso fazer uma verificação em dois campos de um formulário antes de envia-lo.

Preciso verificar se o campo 'estoque_minimo' é menor que o campo 'estoque_maximo'. Já fiz inúmeras tentativas e nenhuma funcionou bem, por incrível que pareça as vezes funciona e outras não (as vezes as condições são simplesmente ignoradas).

Esse é meu código:

Na tag FORM juntamento com o BUTTON está assim (não vou colocar todo formulário por ser grande, e o meu interesse está apenas nos 2 campos que vou inserir)

```js
function validaFormulario(){
 var estoque_minimo;
 var estoque_maximo;

 estoque_minimo = $('#estoque_minimo').val();
 estoque_maximo = $('#estoque_maximo').val();

 if(estoque_minimo >= estoque_maximo){
  alert('voce está fazendo isso errado...');
 }
 else{
  $('#formCadastroProdutos').submit();
 }                
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formCadastroProdutos" method="POST" action="cadastra_produto.php">
  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <label for="estoque_minimo">Estoque minimo</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="estoque_minimo" name="estoque_minimo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
      <label for="estoque_maximo">Estoque máximo</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="estoque_maximo" name="estoque_maximo">
  </div>

  <button onclick="validaFormulario()" id="btn_cadastra_produto" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
      Salvar
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Fiz dessa forma, porque vi em um post parecido por aqui...
Fico no aguardo de sugestões, desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas declare as `variáveis` dentro do evento de `click`, assim, os valores dos `inputs` serão capturados sempre que houver a ação e usando a função `Math.max()`, verificamos o maior número entre os dois `inputs`, caso o maior for do input `estoque_minimo` ele entra no `if` caso não for, ele entra no `else`.

```js
$('#btn_cadastra_produto').click(function(){
var estoque_minimo = $('#estoque_minimo').val();
var estoque_maximo = $('#estoque_maximo').val();

var max = Math.max(estoque_minimo, estoque_maximo);
if(max == estoque_minimo){
 alert('voce está fazendo isso errado...');
}
else {
//$('#formCadastroProdutos').submit();
    alert('ok,enviado')
}                
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formCadastroProdutos" method="POST" action="cadastra_produto.php">

        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="estoque_minimo">Estoque minimo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estoque_minimo" name="estoque_minimo">
        </div>
                            
        <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
            <label for="estoque_maximo">Estoque máximo</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="estoque_maximo" name="estoque_maximo">
        </div>

        <button 
        id="btn_cadastra_produto" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            Salvar
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span>
        </button>

</form>
```

Comment: Jorge, primeiramente obrigado pela resposta. Eu tentei da forma como você explicou, mas acontece que ao persistir ele acaba enviando o formulário mesmo não satisfazendo as condições. Eu testei assim: coloquei 7 em estoque minimo e 5 no estoque máximo, cliquei no botão e ele não enviou o formulário, até aqui tudo bem. Porém, se eu editar o estoque minimo para 10, ou algum número maior que contenha 2 dígitos ou mais, ele ignora a condição proposta. É esse o problema que acontece com praticamente todos métodos que testei até agora, não consigo entender porque a condição é ignorada...

Comment: @ReginaldoBoeke editei a resposta, utilizei o `Math.max()` para capturar o maior valor, depois apenas verifiquei se o `estoque_minimo` era o maior. Testa ai!

Comment: Ei Jorge. Funcionou certinho, muito obrigado! Não conhecia esse Math.max(), comecei estudar desenvolvimento web a pouco tempo rsrs. Muito obrigado mesmo, agora vou dar uma pesquisada pra entender como funciona o Math.max(). Abraço!

Comment: @ReginaldoBoeke por nada! Se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como correta :) Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Reginaldo,

você pode adicionar na declaração do seu Form o seguinte código
 `onsubmit="return validaFormulario()"`

ficando da seguinte maneira: `<form id="formCadastroProdutos" method="POST" action="cadastra_produto.php" onsubmit="return validaFormulario()">`

e modificar seu método para retornar boolean caso esteja OK ou não

```
function validaFormulario(){
var estoque_minimo;
var estoque_maximo;

estoque_minimo = $('#estoque_minimo').val();
estoque_maximo = $('#estoque_maximo').val();

if(estoque_minimo >= estoque_maximo){
    alert('voce está fazendo isso errado...');
    return false;
}
else{
    $('#formCadastroProdutos').submit();
    return true;
}                
}
```

Essa solução é mais adotada que eventos `onClick` por ser mais segura, é importante sinalizar para o usuário onde ele errou também.

Comment: Olá Matheus, obrigado por sua resposta. Então, dessa forma eu teria que mudar meu button pra type="submit" certo? Eu fiz dessa forma e não funcionou... Anteriormente eu havia tentado uma solução parecida com essa que você explicou, e acontecia o mesmo da solução do Jorge acima. Ele funciona em alguns casos, mas quando coloco por exemplo 5 no estoque minimo e 4 no maximo, ele não envia o formulário, até aqui tudo bem. Mas se eu editar o estoque minimo colocando um número como 10 ou maior (pelo que me parece qualquer número com 2 dígitos ou mais) ele ignora a condição e submete o formulário :)